# Embedding multiple videos causes error in youtube api

Tags: air, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using several `HTMLLoader` to embed youtube videos in an Air app (one per loader), and when I add more than two, it causes an error in the API for all players past the second. The player seems to work fine, but the events are never called, and player.pauseVideo is undefined.

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'b' [undefined] is not an object.
at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflJ4hakx.js : 206
at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflJ4hakx.js : 205
at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflJ4hakx.js : 204
at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflJ4hakx.js : 199
```

My embed code:

```
function SetupYoutubePlayer(divName, videoID) {
    _videoID = videoID;
    _divName = divName;
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

var _videoID;
var _divName;

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player(_divName, {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        wmode: 'opaque',
        autohide: '1',
        modestbranding: '1',
        frameborder: "0",
        showinfo: '0',
        videoId: _videoID,
        playerVars: { 
            'wmode': 'opaque', 
            'rel': 0, 
            'autohide': 1,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'frameborder': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
        },
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're repeatedly calling the following lines:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Those only need to be executed once, to pull in the `YT.Player` definition and associated API. Do things work as expected if you make sure that's only executed once?

Comment: Those lines are only called once for each `HTMLLoader`, and each loader has a single video

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious to someone more familiar with Adobe Air, but does each HTMLLoader have a completely separate JavaScript environment?

Comment: Yes, I think they behave similar to separate tabs in a browser

Comment: If your issue only crops up where you have multiple `HTMLLoader` instances then there's SOME sort of shared environment state at play here, but unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough about the Air runtime to diagnose exactly what's going on.

Comment: After further testing, I found it only happens when I load the pages from a remote site, loading from file:// works fine

Comment: From stepping through the relevant source, it appears that the function `a.getApiInterface()`, where `a` is the embedded youtube flash player, is returning undefined instead of an array containing the string names of the api functions. 

Delaying starting the `HTMLLoader` load by 5 seconds after the previous one finishes will consistently cause the error starting from the second one instead of the third.